# How to get Map<Integer,Integer> using Collectors.toMap?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have `List<StudentRecord> records` containing `StudentRecord` instances.

```
public class StudentRecord {

private String lastName;
private String firstName;
private int mark;

//constructor + getters
}
```

How do I make `Map<Integer,Integer>` that as key has mark and as value, number of mark occurances in records list? Note: I have to use exactly this method [toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-).

I have tried this myself:
 `Map<Integer,Integer>mapaPoOcjenama2=
records.stream()
.collect(Collectors.toMap(StudentRecord::getMark, Collectors.counting(), mergeFunction));`

But I am now sure how Collectors.counting() works and dont know what to write as merge function.

Comment: You want to use `Collectors.groupingBy(r -> r.getMark(), Collectors.counting());` not toMap which is for one value per key

Comment: My task is, to use toMap as specified.

Comment: In that case you can use `Collectors.toMap(StudentRecord::getMark, 1, (a, b) -> a == null ? b : a + b)` though I wouldn't do that as it's confusingly complicated.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: the `null` test is obsolete, as there is no `null` in the source values. On the other hand, the second argument must be a function; a constant will not be accepted. So the collector would be `Collectors.toMap(StudentRecord::getMark, r->1, (a, b) -> a + b)` or `Collectors.toMap(StudentRecord::getMark, r->1, Integer::sum)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that's fairly easy to with `toMap`:

```
collect(Collectors.toMap(StudentRecord::getMark, 
        s -> 1, 
        (left, right) -> left + right));
```

The first argument is a `Function` that maps the `Key` in the map.

The second is a `Function` that maps the `Value` in the map. Since you need to count them, it will always return 1.

And the third is a `BiFunction` that says how to merge two keys in case they are the same. Since you want to count, you will increment by one all the time.